# Is it possible to join two password protected Disque instances?

Tags: message-queue, disque

Let's say I have two Disque instances:

One instance is running on port 7711 with ip address 12.34.567.890 and password foo.

Another instance is running on port 7712 with ip address 98.76.543.210 and password bar.

I'm able to connect to either instance by typing:

`./disque -h 12.34.567.890 -p 7711 -a foo`
or
`./disque -h 98.76.543.210 -p 7712 -a bar`

If I want to join these instances together using the `CLUSTER MEET` command, is this possible?

I noticed a smilar thread relating to [redis cluster](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/redis-db/Z8lMxTfDct8).

I'm hoping to run Disque in a docker container with other services on a single server, so I'd like to have keep it password protected.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to join them because the inter node communication happens on ports that are not password protected. But if you use different passwords it won't be easy for the client to reconnect to a different node in case a node fails. For that reason, it will work better if you use the same password for all the nodes in the cluster.

Comment: Isn't this a security vulnerability? What if I find the IP address/port for a password protected Disque instance(instance A), spin up my own Disque instance(instance B) and join it to Instance A. Jobs will replicate from the password protected Instance A to my Instance B...and I would be able to see all jobs from Instance A?

Comment: You need to protect the port where the cluster bus is operating. For that, you have to use firewall rules.